# Como adicionar itens dinamicamente em um ListView que está dentro de um Fragment?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um *layout* em um aplicativo para Android que será utilizado em Tablets, basicamente o *layout* principal possui uma *Toolbar*, um *DrawerLayout*, um *FrameLayout* e um *Fragment*, conforme está abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/default_toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/history_frag"
                class="br.com.exemplo.HistoryFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                tools:layout="@layout/history_fragment" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

O `content_frame` é responsável por acomodar os *fragments* de acordo com a opção selecionada e o `history_frag` é um *fragment* fixo, esse *fragment* possui o *layout*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_history"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollView"
        android:text="@string/lbl_clear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para adicionar dinamicamente novos itens no *ListView* que fica dentro do `history_frag`, através do *fragment* atual que está no `content_frame`. Tentei fazer isso:

```
// Fragment qualquer que está no content_frame, todos os fragments que serão chamados 
// possuem um Button chamado btnRandom.
public class ExemploFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exemplo_fragment, container, false);

        Button btnRandom = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnRandom);

        btnRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // aqui é adicionado um novo item ao history_frag
                HistoryFragment historyFrag = (HistoryFragment) getActivity().
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.history_frag);
                if (historyFrag != null) {
                    historyFrag.addHistory("Um item qualquer");
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

A classe *HistoryFrament* está assim:

```
public class HistoryFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    private List<String> mList;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mList.add("a");
        mList.add("b");
        mList.add("c");
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fragment, container, false);

        Button btnClear = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mArrayAdapter.clear();
                mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public void addHistory(String history) {
        if (mArrayAdapter != null) {
            mArrayAdapter.add(history);
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Fazendo dessa maneira, somente o primeiro item é adicionado ao *ListView*, tentei depurar o código e os itens são passados para o *HistoryFragment* corretamente, só não são atualizados. Também tentei chamar o `notifyDataSetChanged();` dentro do `runOnUiThread`, mas não funcionou. Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Como está o código do seu `Adapter`?

Comment: @Wakim, atualizei o código, tentei adicionar alguns itens diretamente pelo código, mas também não foi, somente o primeiro item é exibido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você colocou um `ListView` dentro de um `ScrollView`, o que é desnecessário porque o `ListView` já faz a gerência dos itens que são exibidos no espaço que é dado para ele se "renderizar".

Entendo que vocẽ quer forçar que o `TextView` e o `Button` apareçam e o `ListView`  ocupe o resto do espaço disponível. Dando uma sugestão seria:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_clear" />
</LinearLayout>
```

O truque nesse caso é usar o `layout_height="0dp"` e o `layout_weight="1"`, com isso você força com que o `ListView` ocupe todo o espaço disponível após o cálculo de tamanho dos demais filhos do mesmo pai.